# Is there any way to automatically take a picture through front camera javascript on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

Basically what i am trying to do is create a web page where user can click a button which will open up the image uploader and select camera from there to open phone's native camera. Now i want to automate the process of taking picture i.e. rather than having the user press the capture button the picture should automatically be captured and returned in javascript. Please help.

I am already done automating the procedure to open camera just need to automate the picture taking button tap

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
    <button>Open File Dialog</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("button").on("click", function() {
        $("input").trigger("click");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above is the code which is working fine but the camera opened up is not automated. Please help

Comment: Think of the security implications of a phone browser that allowed JavaScript to trigger the camera.

Comment: I would look into Cordova.

Comment: getUserMedia is probably helpful here https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/6403122

Comment: @TedBrownlow Yea thats what i thought but that can't be triggering programatically :D . So what i did was to handle this in a human clicked function which has partially solved the problem. But yea thanks for the help it solved it in a way.